# Amber light on Powervault md3060e

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell, dell-powervault

While doing maintenance on another server I noticed an amber light on one draw of a Powervault md3060e (linked to a Poweredge r720d).

There is no amber light for the drives of the draw. Every drives are OK according to the RAID controller.

I have read a lot of dell documentation regarding this and it seems that my only solution is to manage to install MDSM (Modular Disk Storage Manager).

However the Poweredge server is running on Fedora.

I can not find any procedure to install the MDSM tool on Fedora and I do not have any idea of how to do it.

Does any one know how I could troubleshoot this (with MDSM or any other tool) ?

PS: If I manage to migrate the server to Ubuntu does it increase the chances to manage to install MDSM ?

Comment: Googling "dell linux repo" finds https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/ , give it a try. And, check HCL for your hardware, is Fedora listed?